# Add numbers to filename

Tags: c, string, scope, undefined-behavior

I want to store data in different files. Therefore I want to create files as follows: `data_1.log`, `data_2.log`, ..., `data_N.log`. The appendix `.log` is not necessary but would be nice. All my approaches failed so far. Here is one sample that is probably close to what I need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char get_file_name(int k){ 
    int i, j;
    char s1[100] = "logs/data_";
    char s2[100];
    snprintf(s2, 100, "%d", k);
    for(i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    for(j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; ++j, ++i){
        s1[i] = s2[j];
    }
    s1[i] = '\0';
    return s1;
}

int main(){

    char file_name[100];
    for(int k=0; k<10; k++){
        // Get data
        // ...
        // Create filename
        strcpy(file_name, get_file_name(k));
        printf("%s", file_name);
        // fp = fopen(file_name, "w+");
        // Write data to file
        // print_results_to_file();
        // fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

At the moment I get the following errors which I don't understand:

```
    string.c: In function ‘get_file_name’:
string.c:14:12: warning: returning ‘char *’ from a function with return type ‘char’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     return s1;
            ^~
string.c:14:12: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
string.c: In function ‘main’:
string.c:24:27: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         strcpy(file_name, get_file_name(k));
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from string.c:2:
/usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~
```

Is there a more simpler way to create such filenames? I can't believe that there isn't one.

Comment: your build is failing because you did not define the `print_results_to_file();` method.

Comment: The first warning is pretty clear: you return a char* while your return type is only a char. HOWEVER, take care of the second warning: you're returning the address of a local variable!

Comment: Did you even read errors?

Comment: Posting error messages is a good thing, but you should also read them, try to understand them and google them. A simple google on "function returns address of local variable" would give you very detailed explanations of what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various issues with this code and rather than correcting them one by one here’s an alternative approach. It’s not the only one but it’s simple and should be easy to understand and adapt:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void get_file_name(int k, char* buffer, size_t buflen) {
    snprintf(buffer, buflen, "logs/data_%d.log", k);
}

int main() {
    const size_t BUFLEN = 50;
    char file_name[BUFLEN];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        get_file_name(i, file_name, BUFLEN);
        printf("%s\n", file_name);
        // Code for writing to file.
    }
}
```

A few details:

1. Rather than attempting to return (pointers to) memory, this function passes a buffer that is written to. It’s up to the caller to ensure that the buffer is big enough (this is always the case here, but if the actual filenames are longer, you should add logic that inspects the return value of `snprintf` and performs appropriate error handling).
2. The actual logic of the function requires only a single call to `snprintf`, which already performs everything you require, so it’s unclear whether having a separate function is even necessary or helpful.
3. The above uses variable-length arrays. If you want to ensure constant buffers, you can use a `#define` instead of a `const size_t` variable for the buffer length. However, using a variable-length array here is fine, and some compilers even convert it into a constant array.

As mentioned in comments, it’s important that you (a) read and understand the documentation of the functions you’re using, and (b) read and understand the compiler error messages.

Comment: the reason of -2- is coming from Shadok motto: _why make simple when you can do complicated_ ^^

Comment: It's probably better for `get_file_name()` to check if the buffer length supplied is sufficient, and return an appropriate indication to the caller (which can then provide a sufficient buffer, if desired).  `snprintf()` can help with that.

Comment: @Peter See my note 1. I’d rather keep it simple enough for OP to understand, since in any case the buffer size 50 is ample to hold *any* value for this example, and — in this specific case — no check is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The function `get_file_name` has return type `char`

```
char get_file_name(int k){
```

but it returns an object of type `char *`

```
char s1[100] = "logs/data_";
//...
return s1;
```

Moreover the returned pointer points to a local array `s1` that will not alive after exiting the function.

In this call

```
strcpy(file_name, get_file_name(k));
```

the type of the second argument (that is `char` according to the function `get_file_name` declaration) shall be `char *`.

There is neither the function `print_results_to_file` declaration nor its definition.

According to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

I would write the function `get_file_name` the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * get_file_name( char *file_name, size_t n, size_t padding )
{
    const char *common_part = "logs/data_";

    snprintf( file_name, n, "%s%zu", common_part, padding );

    return file_name;
}    

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char file_name[N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) puts( get_file_name( file_name, N, i ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
logs/data_0
logs/data_1
logs/data_2
logs/data_3
logs/data_4
logs/data_5
logs/data_6
logs/data_7
logs/data_8
logs/data_9
```

Comment: Regarding your last point, OP’s code doesn’t just declare `main` but define it. And inside a *definition*, the `void` in the parameter list can be omitted. That is, `int main()` is the same as `int main(void)` in a definition.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No it may not be ignored. See the C Standard.

Comment: Right, see ISO/IEC 9899:2011, section 6.9.1 par 1. The declaration-list is optional. See also example `int g() { /* … */ }` in footnote 162.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are mistaken. Yes the declaration list is optional for a function declaration. But void shall be specified for a function definition. And moreover see the C Standard about how the function main shall be declared.

Comment: I’m citing the section on function *definitions*. Please read the cited section before continuing to argue.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It seems you incorrectly understand it.  The function main does not have an indentifier list. It has a parameter type list that accordinbg to the section "5.1.2.2.1 Program startup" either is empty and in this case the function is declared like int main(void) { /* ... */ } or has two type parameters int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }

Comment: Again, according to the footnote (substituting `g` with `main`), the function definition `int main() {…}` is a valid definition, and has type compatible with `int main(void)`, and is thus a valid definition of the program startup function. Regardless, a *prototype declaration* `int main()` would *also* be valid (but unnecessary) because it’s compatible with both `int main(void)` and `int main(int, char**)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have found only one footnote "10) Thus, int can be replaced by a typedef name defined as int, or the type of argv can be written as
char ** argv, and so on." It has nothing common with what you are writing.

Comment: That footnote is irrelevant here, the relevant footnote is the one I cited earlier. Anyway, the C11 standard itself contains `int main() {…}` as valid example code *multiple times*, e.g. in section 6.5.3.4 par 8. Of course it’s possible that these are defects in the standard but nothing suggests this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph See the section "5.1.2.2.1 Program startup" .

Comment: Why do you keep ignoring my comments and keep pointing me to a section that I’ve obviously read, and which does not contradict anything I’ve written?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Type category is not the same as how main shall be declared according to the C Standard.

Comment: It’s not the same, but it’s relevant. In fact, section 5.1.2.2.1 explicitly says the declaration shall be “equivalent” to the ones shown. But *even if it didn’t say that*, it would be implied unless the standard explicitly stated the opposite. You also keep ignoring the fact that the standard itself uses `int main() {…}` as valid code in two places.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It can be a typo.:) You can ask your question to the C Standard Committee. The question was discussed many times..

Comment: It could be a typo … in two independent places. But *nothing indicates that it is*. If the question was indeed discussed many times, then why are the examples still included in the newest version of the C standard, if they’re typos?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am not ignoring you. But the question as I said was discussed many times. If you were right then in the Startup section there was placed the alternative main declaration that you are referring.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, but the biggest one is that you are trying to return a pointer to a local variable from `get_file_name`.

This is a big no no since the memory allocated for `char s1[100]` in `get_file_name` is freed immediately after `return`.

The rest of the errors are because you forgot the `*` in `char get_file_name(int k)`.

There are several possible solutions:

1. Pass in a `char` array for the function to fill.
2. Use a global variable (This is considered a bad practice).
3. Dynamically allocate the memory.
4. Make the local variable static (this is a bit hacky, but legal)

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are easily explained:

`get_file_name` should return a `char` but you create a `char[]` and return this(it isthe same as `char*`)

`get_file_name` returns the adress of an array that is created in the function itself. After the function ends, the array may be overwritten. Add the array as parameter or use `malloc`

`strcpy` does not work because it expects a `char*` (`char[]`) and not a `char`. `get_file_name` returns a `char`.

`print_results_to_file` is not defined. You may need to include other files you use in the program (e.g. if the function is implemented in a file `func.c` the prototype should be in a file called `func.h` that is included via `#include "func.h"`.